# Headings must have content and the content must be accessible by a screen reader React v.6

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Created a random number generator application in React. According to the idea, you can choose different cubes and the value of the faces of the cubes is included in the value of the button. But it turns out that when the application is first loaded, an error occurs that the value of the button variable cannot be empty. What should I do in this situation?

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Dice.css'

const diceButton = document.querySelector('.dice__button');
const btnD6 = document.getElementById("btn_d6");
const btnD20 = document.getElementById("btn_d20");
const btnD4 = document.getElementById("btn_d4");

//d20
function d20(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(20);
    var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="&nbsp;" + res;
}

//d6
function d6(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(6);
    var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="&nbsp;" + res;
}

//d4
function d4(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(4);
    var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="&nbsp;" + res;
}


function dropD6() {
    diceButton.addEventListener('click', d6);
    document.getElementById("dice__button").innerHTML = "Кинуть d6:";
    document.getElementById("dice__type").innerHTML = "d6:";
}

function dropD20() {
    diceButton.addEventListener('click', d20);
    document.getElementById("dice__button").innerHTML = "Кинуть d20:";
    document.getElementById("dice__type").innerHTML = "d20:";
}

function dropD4() {
    diceButton.addEventListener('click', d4);
    document.getElementById("dice__button").innerHTML = "Кинуть d4:";
    document.getElementById("dice__type").innerHTML = "d4:";
}


diceButton.addEventListener('click', d20);
btnD6.addEventListener('click', dropD6);
btnD20.addEventListener('click', dropD20)
btnD4.addEventListener('click', dropD4)

const Dice = () => {
    
  return (
    <>
        <div class="main__div">
            <div class="dices__main">
                <div class="d20">
                    <div class="dice_tw">
                        <h1 class="dice_tw_screen" >Значение&nbsp;</h1>
                        <h1 class="dice_tw_screen" id="dice__type">d:</h1> 
                        <h1 class="dice_tw_screen" id="demo"></h1> 
                    </div>
                    <button class="dice__button" type="button" id="dice__button">Выбери дайс</button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="t">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d4">d4</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d6">d6</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d8">d8</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d10">d10</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d12">d12</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <button class="dice__button_1" id="btn_d20">d20</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dice
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <button> is for use inside forms, and is older -- use <input type="button"> instead! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, it doesn't work(